Run string as query through macro - error parameters must precede keyword
I'm trying to accomplished this task using SAS.
I have a table PRODUCTS with columns product, date_start, query.
Column query has a string with that is a query I want to run through macro and call execute.
For now, I have only one query, following:
CREATE TABLE RESULT AS 
  SELECT T1.COL1, T1.COL2, T1.COL3, SUM(T2.VALUE) AS VALUE 
  FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
  ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL1 AND T1.COL2 = T2.COL2 
  WHERE T2.COL5 = 'A'
;

And then a I run the following code:
%MACRO RUN_QUERY(PARAM1);
    PROC SQL;
        &PARAM1
    ;QUIT;
%MEND RUN_QUERY;


DATA _NULL_;
    SET PRODUCTS;
    CALL EXECUTE('%RUN_QUERY(PARAM1='||QUERY||');');
RUN;

And I got an error:
ERROR: All positional parameters must precede keyword parameters.

What's going on? And how to solve it?
I suspect it is related to dots used in the query string.

Do you mean to say you have dataset named PRODUCTS with a variable named QUERY that has content like 'create table ... T1.COL1, T1.COL2, ....' with COMMAS in it?  If so then of course the macro processor is seeing positional arguments.

This has to do with commas in your query being passed into the function. From SAS's perspective, this is what the program is doing:
%RUN_QUERY(PARAM1=CREATE TABLE RESULT AS SELECT T1.COL1, T2.COL2, ...);
Those commas are a problem because SAS is parsing them as positional parameters. That is, SAS thinks these are individual arguments in the function:

CREATE TABLE RESULT AS SELECT T1.COL1
T2.COL2
T3.COL3
SUM(T2.VALUE) AS VALUE FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON ...

You need to quote it with a macro quoting function to tell SAS that the entire string is one argument:
%RUN_QUERY(PARAM1=%bquote(CREATE TABLE RESULT AS SELECT T1.COL1, T2.COL2, ...));
Now let's translate this into a DATA Step call execute statement. The fixed program looks like this:
DATA _NULL_;
    SET PRODUCTS;
    CALL EXECUTE('%RUN_QUERY(PARAM1=%bquote('||QUERY||'));');
RUN;

Let's test this:
data products;
    infile datalines dlm='|';
    length query $500.;
    input query$;
    datalines;
create table test as select make, model, horsepower from sashelp.cars
;
run;

%MACRO RUN_QUERY(PARAM1);
    PROC SQL;
        &PARAM1
    ;QUIT;
%MEND RUN_QUERY;


DATA _NULL_;
    SET PRODUCTS;
    CALL EXECUTE('%RUN_QUERY(PARAM1=%bquote('||QUERY||'));');
RUN;

NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set WORK.PRODUCTS.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds

NOTE: CALL EXECUTE generated line.
1         + PROC SQL;
1         + create table test as select make, model, horsepower from sashelp.cars
2         +
3         +              ;
NOTE: Table WORK.TEST created, with 428 rows and 3 columns.


If you want to pass commas into a macro (or macro function) call as part of the values of the arguments and not the delimiter between the arguments then you need to add macro quoting.
Put it would probably in your case to be simpler to rewrite the macro to expect that the value is enclosed in actual quotes.
%macro run_query(param1);
proc sql;
 %sysfunc(dequote(&param1));
quit;
%mend run_query;

Then your data step can add the quotes.
data _null_;
  set products;
  call execute(cats('%nrstr(%run_query)(param1='
      ,quote(trim(query),"'"),')'))
  ;
run;

